# Can a CSS ::after pseudo-element be fitted to the size of its parent?

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I want to put a gradient over an image. Is there a way to do this using an ::after element in CSS?
The dimensions of the image are not known and the position is static.

HTML:

```
<span class="gradient">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZ2WS.gif">
</span>
```

CSS:

```
.gradient img::after{
    content: "";
    background-image: linear-gradient(#000, #ffffff00);
}
```

Is there any way to position this ::after so that it fits fully above the image?

Comment: position:relative then absolute to the pseudo will do. mix-blend-mode could also work without a pseudo

Comment: `img` cannot have `::after` or `::before`. Only elements that can have children do.

Comment: @connexo Ah, thank you! Moving it to the `span` instead of the `img` works great!

Answer (score 0):

`position` and `display` could do:

```css
span {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

span::after {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: "";
  background-image: linear-gradient(#000, #ffffff00);
}
```

```html
<span class="gradient">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZ2WS.gif">
</span>
```

`mix-blend-mode` and `display` too :

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#000, #ffffff00);
}
img {
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

```html
<span class="gradient">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZ2WS.gif">
</span>
```